# Decrement a value after clicking a button in the same row - knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table which I fill with some numbers. There is a button in each row. After clicking this button I would like to decrement a counter in this row. How to to this with knockout?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class=panel-heading>Title</div>
    <table class=table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Counter</th>
                <th>Increment</th>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: counter"></td>             
            <td> <input type="button" value="increment" data-bind=??? ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;   
    self.records = ko.observableArray([]);   

    $.getJSON("/data", function(data) {         
      self.records(data);      
    }) 

//function to decrement

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

1. Process data you get from server, turn `counter` property into observable and add function to decrement counter property
2. Restructure you code a little so viewmodel will be created by the time of ajax request
3. Move `applyBindings` call to ajax callback so it would fire when everything has been loaded

So the code would look like:

```
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: counter"></td>             
        <td> <input type="button" value="decrement" data-bind="click: decrement"></td>
    </tr>

    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;   
        self.records = ko.observableArray([]);
    }
    var vm = new AppViewModel();

    // load data from server
    $.getJSON("/data", function(data) {
        data.forEach( function(item) {

          // make counter observable
          item.counter = ko.observable(item.counter);

          // add function to decrement
          item.decrement = function() {
            this.counter( this.counter()-1 );
          }

        })

        // load array into viewmodel
        vm.records(data);

        // apply bindings when all obervables have been declared
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    })
```

Check demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/gc8beag5/)

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work when using data from server - it doesn't load them to the table at all. I thought that moving ko.applyBindings(vm); ater last parenthasis would help and indeed it changed something - now data is loaded but I don't get numbers in counter cells but this strange formula: function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.tb(c[E],arguments[0])&&(c.ga(),c[E]=arguments[0],c.fa()),this;a.l.oc(c);return c[E]} Any ideas what can be changed?

Comment: No, moving `ko.applyBindings(vm);` is a bad idea, it should stay in ajax callback. Better show what you get from server in `data` variable. Can you place `console.dir(data)` before `data.forEach( function(item) {` and see in Chrome console what you've got?

Comment: My code was simplified for the purpose of the question, I have some more columns in the table with different names, but I use freeSeats as counter here (I copied first object): 0: Object
date: "2016-01-09"
decrement: ()
freeSeats: c()
K: Object
Nb: 1
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: "c"
prototype: c
Symbol(_latestValue): "3"
__proto__: Object
<function scope>
from: "Madrid"
price: "30"
to: "Barcelona"
username: "a"
__proto__: Object I don't know if this is readible, I can post content of data if you want. Anyway, data seems fine and it loaded before I added this script

Comment: This is a function named `c`. It is not a JSON object which I presume you expect from server. A JSON object would look something simple like the dummy data from my fiddle. However to test if the code works in your environment replace `item.counter = ko.observable(item.counter)` with `item.counter = ko.observable(100)`.

Comment: It doesn't work. And when I click on data in Network tab in Chrome console I have nicely formatted records like: {"from":"Madrid","to":"Barcelona","date":"2016-01-09","price":"30","freeSeats":"3","username":"a"}

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle and copy there html, javascript you have and response from network console? It doesn't need to run without errors. I will check it

Comment: I don't think you can check it in jsfiddle since you can't make get request there (as far as I know). When I copy the data I get from server and use them as in your JSFiddle it works fine. So the data must be fine. Problem is only when using  $.getJSON.

Comment: Yes ajax won't work but I wanted to take a look at full code and data from server. Also you can try to switch to simple ajax so the response would not be processed internally by jQuery and see if it goes through

Comment: Just as you said the JSON is fine. Try to use simple get ajax and output data again: `$.get("/data", function( data ) { console.dir(data) });`. If it works, just parse json yourself - `var data = JSON.parse(data)` and go from there as before.

Comment: Data in console is fine, but unfortunately no changes in the table.

Comment: So it seems like there is some progress. Can you update your fiddle with what you've got now? How does the table look like?

Comment: There is nothing to update in the fiddle. Data in Network tab in 'data' is the same for both get and getJSON (it's fine). Only difference is when using console.dir(data). With simple get it outputs fine (no functions, plain json - I also parse to json on server side). The moment I parse manually with var data = JSON.parse(data), I get the same output as for getJSON - meaning these strange functions etc. And table stays empty for both cases

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to initialize and bind my viewmodel right away, but agree with the other poster that you need an observable.

Here is a solution that continues to create and bind your viewmodel right away, as in your original example, but instead of an array of the raw records you receive back it converts them into their own little model objects that have an observable for the counter and an increment function that can be data bound too. This decouples your data load from the life of the viewmodel, so if you wanted to add a button to load fresh data to overwrite it or anything like that, it's just another call to getData().

```
<!-- ... -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: counter"></td>             
            <td> <input type="button" value="increment" data-bind="click: increment" ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<!-- ... -->

<script>
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;   
    self.records = ko.observableArray([]);   

    self.getData = function(){ /* ... */ };

    self.getFakeData = function(){
      var data = [{ counter: 1 }, { counter: 2}, { counter: 3 }];
      var freshData = data.map(function(record){
            return new AppRecord(record);
      });
      self.records(freshData);      
    };
}

function AppRecord(rawRecord) {
    var self = this;
    self.counter = ko.observable(rawRecord.counter);
    self.increment = function(){
      self.counter(self.counter() + 1);  
    };
}

var vm = new AppViewModel();
vm.getFakeData();   // replace with getData()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

Fiddle, with a getFakeData with sample data: https://jsfiddle.net/4hxyarLa/1/

If you are going to have a lot of rows and are concerned abut memory, you could put the increment function in a prototype method for the AppRecord and access the record via a parameter on the function, or you could add the function to the AppViewModel and bind to $parent.increment to call it and access the record via parameter passed to that function to increment it's counter property.